# Get WooCommerce product terms for all products shown in a category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've made a category in WooCommerce. In this category I've an amount of X products. All of my products has some terms.

Now I want to display all product related terms in my category from the available products there.

For example I've product A, B & C.

A has term: H
B has term: K
C has term: Z

Product A & C are in category 1. So I want just the terms H & Z shown in this category.

I've tried this here but this returns all available product terms, also from the products outside of the category:

```
$terms = get_terms('product_tag');
```

Comment: Look inside docs what get_terms() does. You probably need to get all products and collect all terms found.

Answer (score 1):

You will get the each products Ids inside your loop in category page.

So you can use that Product id in below code.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $your_product_id, 'product_tag' );
```

You need to replace function `get_the_terms` instead of `get_terms`.

That way you will get the each products tag in category page. 
Try it and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: On the category page I've more then just one product so this can't work :)